# Extract Information from colon seperated .txt file, C++

Tags: c++, string, fstream

guys. I'm writing this small test program to read the text file from "EXAMPLE.txt" into my main program. At the output, I put "*" to displayed the data during the output is the data that I want to extract it out and locate into an array. Let say, in this test program the data that I wanted to extract is "**JY9757AC**", "**AZ9107AC**","**GY9Z970C**".  But after that, I have did a try run and I faced this problem when comes to the output.

EXAMPLE.txt

```
ABC:JY9757AC
HDMI:AZ9107AC
SNOC:GY9Z970C
```

MAIN.CPP

```
main()
{
    string output;
    ifstream readExample;
    readExample.open("EXAMPLE.txt");  

    while(readExample.eof())
    {
        getline(readExample,output,':');
        cout << "* " << output <<endl; 
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
* ABC       //while loop output the "ABC", which is the data that I don't want.
* JY9757AC
HDMI        //it work's well, as what I expected and so and the SNOC below
* AZ9107AC
SNOC
* GY9Z970C
```

I have no any idea why is the "*** ABC**" is shown on the output, is there anything wrong with my logic. or I missed out something inside the while loop? Thank You in advance for helping to solve my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output stores the first extraction from Example.txt and prints it followed by *. In the first iteration `output = "ABC";` in the second iteration `output = "JY9757AC";`. I have added a `getline()` in the while loop that reads the unwanted part of the line. I also added a `string[]` to store the extracted values in.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string output, notWanted, stringArray[3];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream readExample;
    readExample.open("EXAMPLE.txt");

    while (!readExample.eof())
    {
        getline(readExample, notWanted, ':');
        getline(readExample, output);
        cout << "* " << output << endl;
        stringArray[i++] = output;
    }
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin, implemented your code on my program. The output of the programs produce extra line of "GY9Z970C".

Comment: Thats strange, it doesn't do that for me. Are you sure its the same?

Comment: yeah, I copy your source code paste it and run again. Still the same. (Feel so wierd! haha)

Comment: There have been no unexpected changes in the EXAMPLE.txt file?

Comment: nope, it remains the same as what I posted on the question.

Comment: Hmmm, im supposed to study... But now i can't let this go! :) Can you step throug your code with the debugger and see what happens?

Comment: Haha, Sorry for bothering you during your study session. Would it be the difference of compiler have difference result? (I'm not sure! haha)

Comment: No worries! :) I don't know either, maybe we have to wait for someone more senior to answer that question! :)

Comment: Alright, haha. I'll try to figure out what happened. Thank You Robin! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The `delim` parameter for `getline` replaces the default delimiter for new line which is "\n".
What you are currently getting as a "line" is:

```
ABC
JY9757AC\nHDMI
AZ9107AC\nSNOC
GY9Z970C
```

What you can do is more something like this (if your output like GY9Z970C) is fixed-size:

```
ssize_t len = getline(readExample,output,':');
cout << "* " << (char*)(output + (len - 8)) <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume the `while` loop is `while(!readExample.eof())`, otherwise there should be no output at all.

Second, to your question, the first `getline(readExample,output,':');` read "ABC" into the `output`, so at the next line it outputs `* ABC`, which is exactly what you got. No surprise.